# Little girl friendly versions of Linux (or themes for Linux)

Tags: linux, themes, linux-distributions

I'm going to install Linux on a PC for a daughter (age 7) of a friend of mine. I recently came across [Hannah Montana Linux](http://hannahmontana.sourceforge.net/Site/Home.html). The parents don't want a commercially branded thing going on, so no Hannah Montana. But I was wondering if there were other Linux distributions - or desktop themes - that would be cool for a 7-year-old girl.

Comment: What's wrong w/ Gentoo? ;)

Comment: Re: What's wrong w/ Gentoo? ;) - What sort of 'kid' are you thinking about!! ;)

Comment: I think we can safely assume you only associate with people whos children are computer prodigies

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**QIMO 4 Kids**](http://www.qimo4kids.com/)

> Qimo is a desktop operating system
>   designed for kids. Based on the open
>   source Ubuntu Linux desktop, Qimo
>   comes pre-installed with educational
>   games for children aged 3 and up.

[image]

Or [**Edubuntu**](http://edubuntu.org/), "Linux for Young Human Beings" (Ubuntu customised for educational use):

[image]

And slightly off-topic: **[OOo4Kids](http://wiki.ooo4kids.org/index.php/Main_Page)** is an educational project. The idea is to provide software for 7 to 12-year-olds, based on OpenOffice.org source code, say, extremely simplified.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The [**Sugar**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_%28desktop_environment%29) desktop is plain and simple, used for the [OLPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Laptop_per_Child) program.

Comment: +1 ... i also like the Xandros easy mode, IIRC it's IceWM http://www.icewm.org/

Answer (score 7):

Just to record it here, there is also a [pink fluffy theme for KDE 4](http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php/Fluffy+Bunny?content=101944).

[image: Pink fluffy desktop]

Comment: very much cliché ... anyway +1 :)

Comment: suitable for all ages IMO

Comment: lol@xkcd reference...

Answer (score 4):

For any Ubuntu flavored system, there are many themes available (I am currently checking KDE) that have fairies and other things typical of little girls. Just go to Display properties, and it will give you a link to download new themes and backgrounds.

Not all are "ready to go" necessarily, but it's a start for something really unique that may get you to be her favorite grown-up. But you may also have to show her how to change it when she changes her ideas of what she wants.

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed a [post announcing another kubuntu variant](http://apachelog.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/fluffy/) called ... "fluffy". Below is a screenshot of plasma widgets. See the post for more screenshots.

[image: fluffy plasma widgets]